# Spectre error messages

Tags: dart

I get the follow error messages running the 
Dart Spectre example "line_primitive":

1. Invalid CSS property name: -webkit-touch-callout
2. Invalid CSS property name: flex-direction
3. Internal error:

   `'package:polymer/polymer_element.dart':

    Error: line 140 pos 27: identifier 'mdv.bindModel' cannot be resolved
         Timer.run(() => mdv.bindModel(root, this));`

I downloaded and ran the example as is with no modifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the current (as of August 6th 2013) release of polymer and the SDK. The next release will include a fix for this. In the meantime you can download a nightly build http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/